# make a pie chart with equal areas and label by group

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, pie-chart

While I am wadding into this with caution, I think a pie chart might be a nice way to show presence-absence data.

Below I create representative data where 10 individuals have binary data (0 or 1) for four different pathogens (AAA:DDD).  I make the data in wide and then long form in advance of using ggplot.

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(ID = as.factor(seq(1,10,1)),
            AAA = as.factor(sample(c(0,1), 10, replace = T)),
            BBB = as.factor(sample(c(0,1), 10, replace = T)),
            CCC = as.factor(sample(c(0,1), 10, replace = T)),
            DDD = as.factor(sample(c(0,1), 10, replace = T)))
head(dat)

library(tidyr)
datLong <- gather(dat, Disease, YesNo, -ID)
head(datLong)
```

For each individual (e.g. each level of ID) I want to create a pie chart. For all individuals the pie charts will have the same shape and form. I want the pie charts to be equally divided into four sections representing the four pathogens (AAA:DDD).  If the animal has the pathogen (YesNo == 1), the pie slice will be filled in, if the individual dos not have the pathogen (e.g. YesNo == 0) the pie slice will be present, but not filled in.

To this end I have made a new column (New) that is NA if the pathogen was not found.

```
datLong$New <- ifelse(datLong$YesNo == 0, NA , as.character(datLong$Disease ))
```

I also created a position (Pos) column to label each pie slice.

```
datLong$Pos <- ifelse(datLong$Disease == "AAA", 0.5, 
                        ifelse(datLong$Disease == "BBB", 1.5,
                        ifelse(datLong$Disease == "CCC", 2.5,
                        ifelse(datLong$Disease == "DDD", 3.5, NA))))
```

Using the code below, I then can make the plot that is mostly correct. However, when a pathogen is NA, it is skipped rather than included but not filled in which results in a mismatch with the labels.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(datLong, aes(x = "", color = New, fill = New)) +
 geom_bar(width = 1, color = "black")+
 geom_text(aes(x= factor(1), y=Pos, label = New), size= 8) + 
 facet_wrap(~ID) +
   scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        panel.grid=element_blank()) +
 guides(colour=FALSE)  + guides(fill=FALSE) + 
 coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

Clockwise, I want to fix the position of each of the pathogens (whether it is present or not) in alphabetical order.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and/or corrections!

Comment: @aosmith I am not sure what you mean by summarize the dataset before plotting given that I only have a single value for each level of disease and ID. Would you mind adding a bit of code and/or posting as an answer...? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this very easily by adding the aesthetic `group = disease`

The plot function now looks like this

```
ggplot(datLong, aes(x = "", color = New, fill = New, group = Disease)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, color = "black")+
  geom_text(aes(x= factor(1), y = Pos, label = New), size = 8) + 
  facet_wrap(~ID) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  guides(colour = FALSE)  + guides(fill = FALSE) + 
  coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

One other thing, rather than using the nested `ifelse`, which really does not scale well, you can use subsetting to give the same result

```
seq(0.5, 3.5, 1)[as.factor(datLong$Disease)]
```

Alternatively, you can use `plyr::mapvalues`

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for the additions and suggestions!